# Reference request - second derivative test for function of two variables that includes details of what you can infer when discriminant is zero

Tags: reference-request, multivariable-calculus, optimization

The second derivative test for functions of two variables as I have learned and taught in calculus classes says, in part, that if at a point $D=f_{xx}f_{yy}-(f_{xy})^2$ is zero then we can tell nothing about whether $f$ is local max, local min or saddle at that point.

I needed a converse of this that said more, so in searching the internet I found this page: http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Second_derivative_test_for_a_function_of_two_variables.
It says that if $D=0$ and if one or both of $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ is positive we can rule out the possibility of local maximum.

Does anyone know a textbook or other reference that I can cite if I need to use this fact (i.e. that if $D=0$ you still may be able to rule out some possibilities)?

Comment: Amzoti - my whole question is about this "slightly different statement". Wikipedia and Stewart's calculus book both say that if D=0 then the test is inconclusive. The link I gave says that it may not be completely inconclusive. I would like a reference to that fact, which is not explained on either of the pages you linked to.

Comment: I was just referring to the references therein, not the page. Since they both list those references, I was supposing those references might help. Sorry for the bother!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reference. "A first course in Optimization theory" by Rangarajan K. Sundaram, 1996 has as part of a theorem (p103, Thm 4.3):

Suppose $f$ is a $C^2$ function on on $\mathcal{D} \subset R^n$ and $x$ is a point in the interior of $\mathcal{D}$. If $f$ has a local maximum at $x$, then $D^2f(x)$ is positive semidefinite.

In the case that $f$ is a function of two variables, we can discover using the discussion on pp53-55 of the same book, that $D^2f(x)$ is positive semidefinite iff $D\geq 0$, $f_{xx}\leq 0$ and $f_{yy}\leq 0$.

So putting it together we can show that $f$ local maximum at a point implies $D\geq 0$, $f_{xx}\leq 0$ and $f_{yy}\leq 0$ at that point.